# Required props undefined in chrome 83

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So after installing chrome 83 one of my pages in my app crashes. It says some of my props that's required is undefined. This only happens in chrome. I've tested in IE 11, Edge, Firefox and it works fine in those. It doesn't happen all the time either in chrome. Especially if i restart my localhost it might work a couple of times and then it starts breaking. I've also checked sha1d on master branch couple of weeks back and it also breaks there. This was never an issue before and started just recently. There has been no code changes for weeks related to that page. Any ideas what can cause this in chrome?

Comment: Do you know what property is undefined?

Comment: @mortb Seems to be everyone in the file. intl, state, match, history, location. If I console.log them they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are saying if problem only started happening recently in chrome, and this could be the failure of the prop-types library, its the library responsible for showing such a warning `a required prop is undefined`.

To make sure that it is indeed the problem of the prop-types library, you can switch environment to production, as this library should not work in prod. If indeed its the problem of this library you could try the following

- Maybe try removing react dev tools and see if problem still happens
- clean install of the library
- update the library

Comment: Thanks for reply. The prop-types seems to be at latest in package.json and before I got to test the react dev tools deactivation, it stopped crashing. Will defenitently test this out when it starts crashing again. Do you react dev tools has an issue with chrome?

Comment: @stAMy i don't know if react dev tools has issue with new chrome, but based on your description the issue seems to be coming from the prop types library, and react dev tools do some integration with this library, so there could be a problem in this integration, or in the prop types library itself